# Interface Builder. How do I toggle between open projects using a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: interface-builder, keyboard-shortcuts

Can someone please remind me how do I toggle between open projects using a keyboard shortcut? I briefly knew how to do this but it has evaporated from my brain and Google is no help.

Comment: Should be on super user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what the shortcut is for switching between open projects, but in OS X in general you can use <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> (backtick) to cycle among windows of an application.

Comment: Yep. Thanks Brian. Love that OS X UI consistancy. Cheers.